# Replace multiple node values with PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

I have a table with 5 columns: `ID | APP_ID | ID_NEU | SOURCE | TARGET`.

Then I have something like this:

```
DECLARE
xml_in_tabelle XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                              <!-- 
                                ****************** 
                                ** Source     :  431
                                ** Source Lang:  de
                                ** Target     :  1011
                                ** Target Lang:  en-gb
                                ** Filename:     f431_1011_de_en-gb.xlf
                                ** Generated By: KRAEMM
                                ** Date:         10-FEB-2016 10:35:49
                                ****************** 
                               -->
                              <xliff version="1.0">
                              <file original="f431_1011_de_en-gb.xlf" source-language="de" target-language="en-gb" datatype="html">
                              <header></header>
                              <body>
                              <trans-unit id="S-2.1-121026922769234943-431">
                              <source>Login</source>
                              <target>Login</target>
                              </trans-unit>
                              <trans-unit id="S-2.1-121027126423248468-431">
                              <source>Logout</source>
                              <target>Logout</target>
                              </trans-unit>
                              </body>
                              </file>
                              </xliff>');
BEGIN
INSERT INTO XML_TEST(source,target, ID,APP_ID)
SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/source') "source", 
       extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/target') "target", 
       extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id') "Trans-ID",
       SUBSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'), INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-', 2, 3)+1) "App_ID"
FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(xml_in_tabelle.extract('/xliff/file/body/trans-unit'))) t
WHERE extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id') not in (SELECT ID FROM XML_TEST);
commit;Than
END;
```

to insert some data into a Table (actually it should be from an xml file, but I don't know how to insert a xml into a table yet. But soon I will find out ;D)

That works pretty fine.

Besides I have a procedure, that is creating a Offset between 2 trans-unit  ID's middle parts in 2 different XML, add them to the ID's and save them as ID_NEU.

```
   -- middle part: <trans-unit id="S-2.1-**xxxxxxxx**-431"> 



DECLARE 
x1_org NUMBER := 0;
x2 NUMBER := 0; 
app_ID_v NUMBER :=0;
offset NUMBER :=0;
xml_1 XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('xml1');

xml_2 XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('xml2');

BEGIN
  SELECT SUBSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'), INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,2)+1
               ,INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,3)-(INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,2)+1))
  INTO x1_org
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(xml_1.extract('/xliff/file/body/trans-unit'))) t
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

  SELECT SUBSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'), INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,2)+1
               ,INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,3)-(INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-',1,2)+1))
  INTO x2
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(xml_2.extract('/xliff/file/body/trans-unit'))) t
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

  SELECT  SUBSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'), INSTR(extractvalue(column_value, '/trans-unit/@id'),'-', 2, 3)+1) "App_ID"
  INTO app_ID_v
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(xml_1.extract('/xliff/file/body/trans-unit'))) t
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

  offset := (x1_org-x2);


  UPDATE XML_TEST
  SET ID_NEU = REPLACE(ID,
                SUBSTR(ID, INSTR(ID,'-',1,2)+1
               ,INSTR(ID,'-',1,3)-(INSTR(ID,'-',1,2)+1))
               ,(SUBSTR(ID, INSTR(ID,'-',1,2)+1
               ,INSTR(ID,'-',1,3)-(INSTR(ID,'-',1,2)+1))+10)
               );

END;
```

**Side node: The offset is always the same between the 2 XML files**

Finally I try to get the values from the table (where the target value probably changed) into my second XML.

I Tried something like this:

```
     select updatexml(XMLTYPE('xml2')
    , '/xliff/file/body/trans-unit[@id="'||ID_NEU||'"]/target/text()',target).getClobVal() 
from XML_TEST;
```

But it doesn't work like I want. (It changes the values only for the actual column)

Can somebody help me?
(I hope you understand what I want, my English is pretty bad)

Comment: You are lacking a quote at `xml_1 XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('xml1);` which should be `xml_1 XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('xml1');`.

Comment: True, but this is just an example . I just cut out the whole xml strings because it would be to long. But thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way to do what I want.
I did it this way:

(I saved the XML as CLOB in a table)

```
DECLARE 
xml_neu clob;

BEGIN     FOR cur_xml_neu in ( SELECT ID, source, target FROM XML_TEST ) LOOP


    SELECT updatexml(XMLTYPE(a.XML_DATA_NEU) 
            , '/xliff/file/body/trans-unit[@id="'||cur_xml_neu.ID||'"]/target/text()', cur_xml_neu.target).getClobVal() INTO xml_neu
            from XML_ABLAGE a JOIN XML_TEST t
            ON a.APP_ID = t.APP_ID
            WHERE rownum = 1;

    UPDATE XML_ABLAGE 
    SET XML_DATA_NEU = xml_neu;

END LOOP;
END;
```

(I LOOP over every row in my table where I saved the changes and write the XML back, bit by bit)